# Find the least value of $n\in N$ for which $(n-2)x^2+8x+n+4>\arcsin(\sin12)+\arccos(\cos12)$ for every $x \in \mathbb {R}$

Tags: trigonometry, quadratics, inverse-function, discriminant

Find the least value of $n\in N$ for which $(n-2)x^2+8x+n+4>\arcsin({\sin12})+\arccos({\cos12})$ for every $x \in \mathbb {R}$

---

$(n-2)x^2+8x+n+4>\arcsin({\sin12})+\arccos({\cos12}) $
$(n-2)x^2+8x+n+4>4\pi-12+4\pi-12$  
$(n-2)x^2+8x+n+4>8\pi-24$

I don't know how to solve further. Please help

Comment: Are $12$s in radian ?

Comment: My calculator suggests that $\arccos(\cos(12))+\arcsin(\sin(12))=0$. See if you can verify this, then this is just a CTS question

Comment: Yes 12s are in radians

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $$\arcsin\sin12+\arccos\cos12=0$$ and $n=2$ is not valid, we need
$$4^2-(n-2)(n+4)<0.$$
Can you end it now?

I got $n>4$ or $n<-6.$

Comment: How do you get $4^2-(n-2)(n+4)<0?$

Comment: It's $\frac{\Delta}{4}<0.$

Comment: Ok i got it,Thank you.

Comment: You are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

Consider $f(x)=\arcsin(\sin x)+\arccos(\cos x)$; then
$$
f'(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\sin^2x}}\cos x+\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\cos^2x}}\sin x=
\frac{\cos x}{\lvert\cos x\rvert}+\frac{\sin x}{\lvert\sin x\rvert}
$$
Note that $7\pi/2<12<4\pi$; one inequality is obvious; the other one is equivalent to $\pi<24/7$, but we know from Archimedes that $\pi<22/7$.

For $x\in(7\pi/2,4\pi)$ we have $\cos x>0$ and $\sin x<0$; thus $f$ is constant over $(7\pi/2,4\pi)$. Since
$$
f(4\pi-\pi/4)=0
$$
and $4\pi-\pi/4\in(7\pi/2,4\pi)$, we conclude that $f(12)=0$.

For $n\le2$, the polynomial $p(x)=(n-2)x^2+8x+n+4$ takes on negative values (it's a concave parabola for $n<1$ and a line for $n=2$).

Assuming $n>2$, you need that the discriminant of $p$ is negative:
$$
64-4(n-2)(n+4)<0
$$
that is
$$
n^2+2n-24>0
$$
so $n>4$.